# confusion with .htaccess code and URL and subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` rewrite code like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [QSA]
```

It works fine for
`http://example.com/education/Main/Category`
where 'education' is root directory. and Main and Category as GET variable.

But in my PHP script, there is a code for printing image from a directory.
code is like this

```
echo '<img src="http://example.com/education/subfolder/4.jpg"  width="328" height="208"  class="placeImage" />';
```

but this looks like `http://example.com/education/subfolder/4.jpg`
where `subfolder` is the name of the folder holding the images, and `4.jpg` is the image path.

But this is not working because of above `.htaccess` file. When I remove above `.htaccess` code, then the image displays. But I need above `.htaccess` code also for my page URL. 
I am confused. Is there any method for printing my image without changing that code.

Answer (score 1):

Try your htaccess like this and see if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /education/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /education/edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That base doesn't look right if this is all supposed to be in the `/education/` directory

Comment: Now worked.. Thank you sir RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]